# How to add Items to the property of class type

Tags: c#, list, oop

Following is my class with aliases List property of class type (MeetingAliases). How to add multiple items to aliases and pass as a parameter along with other TSGetRootObject property data to some method. for eg.

```
TSGetRootObject ts = new TSGetRootObject(); 
ts.aliases ???? //How to add data list here
ts.name = id;
ts.service_type = srvtype;
ts = TransfomationSrv.PostData(ts);

public class TSGetRootObject
{

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<MeetingAliases> aliases { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public bool? allow_guests { get; set; }
}

public class MeetingAliases
{ 
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string alias { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string conference { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Something like this: `ts.aliases = new List<MeetingAliases>(); ts.aliases.Add(new MeetingAliases());`

Comment: how to add data to MeetingAliases property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ts.aliases = new List<MeetingAliases>(); 
ts.aliases.Add(new MeetingAliases
{
    alias = "Some text",
    conference = "Other text"
});
```

I'd recommend that you have a look at [Object Initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

You can also initialize the `aliases` list in the constructor of the `TSGetRootObject`:

```
public class TSGetRootObject
{
    public TSGetRootObject
    {
        aliases = new List<MeetingAliases>();
    }

    //Or in c# 6.0 or higher:
    public List<MeetingAliases> aliases { get; set; } = new List<MeetingAliases>();
}
```

Comment: Note that the second initializer example is only available from C#6

Comment: @GeoffJames - correct :) will add a comment. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @GeoffJames

Answer (score 0):

One option how you can do this would be:

Add a constructor to `TSGetRootObject` where you initialize the `List`. Then add a new object `MeetingAliases` to the `TSGetRootObject` object:

```
TSGetRootObject ts = new TSGetRootObject(); 
ts.aliases.Add(new MeetingAliases {
       alias = "alias",
       conference = "conference",
       description = "description",
       id = 1
    }); 
ts.name = id;
ts.service_type = srvtype;
ts = TransfomationSrv.PostData(ts);

public class TSGetRootObject
{

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<MeetingAliases> aliases { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public bool? allow_guests { get; set; }

    public TSGetRootObject(){
        aliases = new List<MeetingAliases>();
    }
}

public class MeetingAliases
{ 
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string alias { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string conference { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? id { get; set; }
}
```